# How can I get column's caption in TDBGrid?

Tags: delphi, tdbgrid, tfield

How can I get column's caption in `TDBGrid`?

I've tried this but it returns `FieldName` instead caption:

```
DBGrid.Fields[i].DisplayLabel
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just access the `Columns` directly:

```
CaptionText := DBGrid1.Columns[i].Title.Caption;
```

If the columns are out of order, and you need to find a column title for a specific field, you have to look for it first:

```
var
  i: Integer;
  CaptionText: string;
begin
  for i := 0 to DBGrid1.Columns.Count - 1 do
    if DBGrid1.Columns[i].FieldName = 'YourField' then
    begin
      CaptionText := DBGrid1.Columns[i].Title.Caption;
      Break;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Is `i` on `Columns` property the same number as on `Field` property?

Comment: Not always. See my edited answer (I was writing it as you posted the comment).